# How to mix nullsafety and not null safety packages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My app is still using Flutter 1.22.0 and has a lot of packages. Some of the packages are really old and already not maintained by the author but it is still good and we still use it since it's the core of our app.
Currently there's an issue with a package (let's say Package A). And the issue was fixed by the author only in V2 (NullSafety enabled) and the author doesn't have plan to put the fix in V1(Not null safety) of the package. So I don't have a choice but to use the V2 of PackageA since the fix is really important in our app.
But When I build it, there's an error with PackageA that i should use Dart 2.12 and Flutter 2. So I've updated my dart and flutter sdk. After that the error for PackageA is now gone but there's a new error with other old packages since they're not nullsafety yet (not maintained by their authors).

So how can I use the V2 of PackageA and at the same time also use the older packages?

I've tried `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety` but I'm still encountering errors with the old packages...

Comment: Hi, have you find the solution ? I also looking for this, I using 1.22.4 and wish to install null safety lib

Comment: Did anyone of you get the solution for this? I too am in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as easy as simple go to `run=>Debug configurations` in `additional run args` add

```
--no-sound-null-safety
```

[image]